# Error with input number in Controller.php in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I made code about selling something. When I input decimal number for `$req->tile` that is multiple of 0.5 ( like 10.5; 11.0; 15.0), the code is ok, but when I input others `$req->tile (like 10.1; 10,2; 10.9)` the variable `$soDonHienCo` goes to zero.

Thank you for any help or suggestion.

```
public function postMua(Request $req)
    {
        $user = $req->user();

        if ($user->bac < ($req->gold * $req->tile)) // Nếu ko đủ bạc
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error' => 'Bạn không đủ bạc để mua số gold này']);
        }

        $soDon = $req->gold / 1000;
          $tl = $req->tile + 0;

        // Lọc ra các đơn bán gold cùng tỉ lệ
        // Cái nào đăng trước sẽ đc mua trước
        $soDonMua = GiaoDichGold::where('idmua', null)
            ->where('ndhuy', false)
            ->where('idban', '!=', $user->id)
            ->where('tile', $tl)
            ->orderBy('created_at')
            ->take($soDon)->get();

        $us = User::where('id', $req->user()->id)->first(); // Người mua chính là người đang đăng nhập
        foreach ($soDonMua as $goldban) {
            $goldban->idmua = $us->id;
            $goldban->bactruoc = $us->bac;
            $goldban->goldtruoc = $us->gold;
            $goldban->noti = false;
            $goldban->save();

            $us1 = User::where('id', $goldban->idban)->first();
            $us1->bac += $goldban->bacnhan; // tăng bạc cho người bán
            $us1->save();
        }
        // Cập nhật số gold, bạc cho người mua
        $soDonHienCo = $soDonMua->count();
        $us->gold += $soDonHienCo * 1000;
        $us->bac -= $soDonHienCo * 1000 * $req->tile;
        $us->save();

        if($soDonHienCo > 0)
        return redirect()->action('GoldController@getCho')->with(['success' => 'Mua '.($soDonHienCo * 1000).' gold thành công']);
        else
        return redirect()->action('GoldController@getCho')->withErrors(['Không đủ gold hoặc Có lỗi xảy ra']);
    }
```

If I input $req->tile is a multiple of 0.5, the code goes well ($soDonHienCo is > 0). But when I input others number like 10.1 ; 22.2 etc... $soDonHienCo = 0.

Comment: What is mysql column type for GiaoDichGold -> tile?

Comment: You are performing a `equal` comparison of `tile`. Are you sure that `$req->tile` value is existing in your data table `GiaoDichGold `?

Comment: @Manpreet sorry for late rep. Float type.

Comment: @PhucLam Yes it does. The problem is when I input decimal number that is not multiple of 0.5 ( like 10.5; 11.0; 15.0), $soDonHienCo will =0, error will exist (return redirect()->action('GoldController@getCho')->withErrors(['Không đủ gold hoặc Có lỗi xảy ra']);